# Only select images with a non-empty src in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I fix my JavaScript code to only view images where `src` is not empty, because JavaScript returns broken images when the `src` is blank:

```
<div class="image-carousel">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src=""      class="img" >
        <img src="1.jpg" class="img" >
        <img src="3.jpg" class="img" >
        <img src="4.jpg" class="img" >
    </div>
    <div class="bubbles"></div>
    <div class="prev"></div>
    <div class="next"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
let carousels = document.getElementsByClassName('image-carousel');
[].forEach.call(carousels, function (c) {
    let next = c.getElementsByClassName('next')[0],
    prev = c.getElementsByClassName('prev')[0],
    bubblesContainer = c.getElementsByClassName('bubbles')[0],

    // getElementsByClassName returns all the images on the inner div
    inner = c.getElementsByClassName('inner')[0],
    imgs = inner.getElementsByTagName('img').getAttribute("src=''", false),
    currentImageIndex = 0,
    width = 400,
    bubbles = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        let b = document.createElement('span');
        b.classList.add('bubble');
        bubblesContainer.appendChild(b);
        bubbles.push(b);

        b.addEventListener('click', function () {
            currentImageIndex = i;
            switchImg();
        });
    }

    function switchImg () {
       inner.style.left = -width * currentImageIndex + 'px';

        bubbles.forEach(function (b, i) {
            if (i === currentImageIndex) {
                b.classList.add('active');
            } else {
                b.classList.remove('active');
            }
        });
    }

    next.addEventListener('click', function () {
        currentImageIndex++;

        if (currentImageIndex >= imgs.length) {
            currentImageIndex = 0;
        }

        switchImg();
    });

    prev.addEventListener('click', function () {
        currentImageIndex--;

        if (currentImageIndex < 0) {
            currentImageIndex = imgs.length - 1;
        }

        switchImg();
    });

    switchImg();
});
```

Comment: _javascript returns broken images where the src is blank..._ Rather fix this bug instead....

Comment: Please help yourself to see [ask] page and come back and edit the question.

Comment: If you don't *need* to do this in JavaScript, it would be trivial to just add the CSS rule: `.image-carousel img[src=""] {display: none;}`

Answer (score 0):

How about make the img "display=none" witch don't have "src"?

```
[...document.querySelectorAll(".image-carousel img")].forEach(function(v) {
    v.style.display = v.getAttribute("src") ? "" : "none"
})
```

Comment: Answering questions here is good but a code-only answer is not very helpful. It would be a much better answer if you explained what the code does and why it answers the question.

Comment: Thanks , where can i place that code on the javascript

Comment: Given that you're using `.querySelectorAll()`, it would be reasonable to put the `src` check in your selector (e.g. `.querySelectorAll('.image-carousel img[src=""]')`).